# In SQL how I can multiply results obtained in rows into results obtained in columns

Tags: sql, matrix-multiplication

Exist a mode or method to obtained that result? please seem my image in the post[image]
I want my result is a product of numbers in vertical (black line) multiplied by number
horizontal (red line)

Comment: Just trying to understand, you want to take 66.28 and multiple it by 84.5 and 21.1 and 63.4?  Could you give a sample result based on the data in your image?

Comment: Columns called Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, etc. is generally an indication of a bad design.

Comment: 66.28x84.5, 58.76x21.1....in this order

Comment: Try to post readable fieldnames and also table names

Comment: Normalize (as per @Unreason), then note `log(a*b*c...*n)=log(a)+log(b)+log(c)...+log(n)` (as per @Mazhar Karimi).

Comment: @onedaywhen, it's a matrix product that is requested here; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication (but this is a special case where i=j=1 which is basically a dot product of two vectors http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
select cast(exp(sum(log(ExpPeso))) as float) as myresult1, (tda1*tda2*tda3*tda4) as reslutset2  
from TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data by extracting the numbered columns into a table such as

```
Matrix
Name  Value
Tda1    94.5
Tda2    21.1
Tda3    53.4
Tda4    21.1
```

And assuming original table is named table, with columns tda value in column called name and value to multiply with named expression (sorry can't read your column names)

Then you could

```
SELECT matrix.value * table.expression
FROM matrix m INNER JOIN table t
    ON m.name = t.tda_value
```

If you can not change structure then in standard SQL (IMHO) you will have to do case

```
SELECT 
      CASE t.tda_value 
          WHEN "Tda1" THEN Tda1
          WHEN "Tda2" THEN Tda2
          WHEN "Tda3" THEN Tda3
          WHEN "Tda4" THEN Tda4
          ELSE 0
      END * t.expression
FROM table
```

Notes:

- you might want to have ELSE NULL (or skip else).
- some databases have extensions to standard that would allow you to have dynamic columns to rows

EDIT:
Of course and at the risk of stating too obvious, at the end you can do a SUM of the above query.